# Mi custom hook no funciona

Tags: reactjs

Estoy intentando hacer una lógica de eccomerce en donde al darle click al botón comprar este mediante una función tome los datos de dicho producto y los ponga en un array vacío que posteriormente debe ser renderizado para que el cliente vea los productos que esta comprando.

Este primer componente simplemente muestra los productos en forma de carta, y como dije antes tiene un boton para que uno pueda 'comprar' el producto:

```
import { useAddProduct } from './useComponents/useAddProduct'
import { useFakeStore } from "./useComponents/useApi"

export const CardBuy = () => {
  const { store } = useFakeStore()
  const { addProduct } = useAddProduct()

  return (
    <>
    <div>
      {store.map((item)=>{
        return(
          <div key={item.title}>
            <h3>{item.title}</h3>
            <h3>{item.price}</h3>
            <button onClick={()=>{addProduct(item)}}>Comprar</button>
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Los custom hooks provienen de este componente:

```
import { useState } from 'react'; 

export const useAddProduct = () => {
  const [product, setProduct] = useState([]);

  const addProduct = ( item ) => {
    console.log(item)
    const comparison = product.find((productItem) => productItem.id === item.id);

    if (comparison) {
      // El producto ya existe, actualiza la cantidad
      setProduct(
        product.map((productItem) =>
          productItem.id === item.id
            ? { ...productItem, quantity: productItem.quantity + 1 }
            : productItem
        )
      );
    } else {
      // El producto no existe en la lista, agrégalo con cantidad 1
      setProduct([...product, { ...item, quantity: 1 }]);
    }
  };

  return { addProduct, product };
};
```

pero por algun extraño motivo cuando quiero renderizar el 'product' que en teoria contiene la informacion de los productos almacenados en un array este no lo hace, simplemente el array esta vacio en este componente (o llega vacio):

```
import { useAddProduct } from "../useComponents/useAddProduct";

export const CartElement = () => {
  const { product } = useAddProduct();

  return (
    <div>
      {product.length > 0 ? (
        product.map((item) => (
          <div key={item.id}>
            <h3>{item.title}</h3>
            <h3>{item.price}</h3>
          </div>
        ))
      ) : (
        <p>El carrito está vacío.</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

¿por no puedo renderizar los productos comprados entonces?

Answer (score 0):

Los estados en react se pierden en cada renderizado de componente. No puedes recuperar la información en un componente distinto porque al llamar al hook, vuelve a su estado original. Si lo que necesitas es pasar información entre componentes necesitas un estado global, o, si son padre e hijo hacer uso de las props.